# Does SqlDataSource automatically convert parameter value…?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

1) ObjectDataSource doesn’t check the type of a supplied parameter, but instead attempts to convert the parameter value into the data type of a matching parameter. Is that also true for SqlDatasource?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

unless you specify a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.type.aspx) for the parameter it will be typed as Object

Comment: So if it is typed as object then SqlDataSource will try to convert it to data type of a matching parameter? Or will it try to convert it regardless of whether you specify a type for it or not?